# Anyone know how I can change the color of the filenames on my modeline in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs

Anyone know how I can change the color of the filenames on my modeline?

[EMACS Themeing http://floatsolutions.net/docs/2010-06-10_1500.png](http://floatsolutions.net/docs/2010-06-10_1500.png).

Here's the theme I'm using:

```
(defun color-theme-twilight ()
  "Color theme by Marcus Crafter, based off the TextMate Twilight theme, created 2008-04-18"
  (interactive)
  (color-theme-install
    '(color-theme-twilight
      ((background-color . "#141414")
        (background-mode . dark)
        (border-color . "black")
        (cursor-color . "#A7A7A7")
        (foreground-color . "#F8F8F8")
        (mouse-color . "sienna1"))
      (default ((t (:background "#141414" :foreground "#CACACA"))))
      (blue ((t (:foreground "blue"))))
      (border-glyph ((t (nil))))
      (buffers-tab ((t (:background "#141414" :foreground "#CACACA"))))
      (font-lock-builtin-face ((t (:foreground "#CACACA"))))
      (font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground "#5F5A60"))))
      (font-lock-constant-face ((t (:foreground "#CF6A4C"))))
      (font-lock-doc-string-face ((t (:foreground "DarkOrange"))))
      (font-lock-function-name-face ((t (:foreground "#9B703F"))))
      (font-lock-keyword-face ((t (:foreground "#CDA869"))))
      (font-lock-preprocessor-face ((t (:foreground "Aquamarine"))))
      (font-lock-reference-face ((t (:foreground "SlateBlue"))))

      (font-lock-regexp-grouping-backslash ((t (:foreground "#E9C062"))))
      (font-lock-regexp-grouping-construct ((t (:foreground "red"))))

      (minibuffer-prompt ((t (:foreground "#5F5A60"))))
      (ido-subdir ((t (:foreground "#CF6A4C"))))
      (ido-first-match ((t (:foreground "#8F9D6A"))))
      (ido-only-match ((t (:foreground "#8F9D6A"))))
      (mumamo-background-chunk-submode ((t (:background "#222222")))) 

      (font-lock-string-face ((t (:foreground "#8F9D6A"))))
      (font-lock-type-face ((t (:foreground "#9B703F"))))
      (font-lock-variable-name-face ((t (:foreground "#7587A6"))))
      (font-lock-warning-face ((t (:background "#EE799F" :foreground "red"))))
      (gui-element ((t (:background "#D4D0C8" :foreground "black"))))
      (region ((t (:background "#27292A"))))
      (mode-line ((t (:background "#3B3B3B" :foreground "white"))))
(mode-line-inactive ((t (:background "#242424" :foreground "#cccddd"))))
        (mode-line-buffer-id ((t (:foreground "#cccddd" :bold t :weight bold))))
(mode-line-emphasis ((t (:foreground "#cccddd" :bold t :weight bold))))
(highlight ((t (:background "#111111"))))
      (highline-face ((t (:background "SeaGreen"))))
      (left-margin ((t (nil))))
      (text-cursor ((t (:background "yellow" :foreground "black"))))
      (toolbar ((t (nil))))
      (underline ((nil (:underline nil))))
      (zmacs-region ((t (:background "snow" :foreground "blue")))))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the `mode-line-buffer-id` line in your theme.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer.  I took me a really long time to figure out that my problem was a bad theme in my themes directory that causing this to not work.  So for anyone out there having trouble setting a theme color, try clearing out your themes directory of old themes.

Answer (score 3):

Just `M-x customize-face mode-line-buffer-id RET`.